# Measuring a subset of a null set

Tags: measure-theory

Which of these following statements is true?

a. There exists a non Lebesgue-measeruable set in $\mathbb{R}$ which gets measurable  with a (not necessarly disjoint) union with a null set.

b. Every subset of a null set is measurable.

c. Every subset of a measurable set is measurable.

I'd say that b is true and that c is wrong, I'm not quite sure about a, can someone help me?

Comment: Did you really means to say that c) is true and b) is wrong or was that a typo?

Comment: In the second half of the sentence in 'a', and in both 'b' and 'c', I assume by "measurable" you mean "Lebesgue measurable". Otherwise, all are false, at least if each statement is universally quantified over all measures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answers for b) and c) are both wrong.  b) is true and c) is wrong.

a): $A=(A\cup N \setminus N) \cup (A \cap N)$. If $A \cup N$ is measurable then  $A\cup N \setminus N$ and $A \cap N$ are both measurable, So $A$ cannot be non-measurable.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I read OP's answer wrongly. Thanks for pointing out.